# In GridLayout, how to get cell from point?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm using a grid layout to hold some rows of text plus some columns of other things.  I want to respond to clicks on each cell with an onClick handler.  How do I determine which cell the user clicked in?

I have put onClick handlers on the text, which works fine.  However, I'm using WRAP_CONTENT on the text so, in most cases, the text does not completely fill up its cell.  If the user taps in the cell but not on the text, the text's onClick handler doesn't respond.  I can easily capture the onClick for the whole GridLayout but then I'm stuck trying to figure out the cell boundaries and determine which cell the user clicked in.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GridView it's trivial as

```
 mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
 mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
 mAdapter = new GridAdapter();
 mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

If you are using `GridLayout` then each of your components should have `onClickListener`. easy way to do it is to make your `Activity` or `Fragment` to implement `onClickListener` and `switch case` on `view.getId()`

Comment: True enough, though I was trying to avoid rewriting some code (and creating an adapter, and so on).

Comment: android still doesn't support magic (-;. there are other options but it depends how you instantiate your views. if dynamically so just add each view it's own designated onClickListener. if by xml you can add `onClick` to the xml of the view to run some function